# How to get the value from MessageHeaderInfo

Tags: wcf, user-interface, soap

I am sending some SOAP headers to a WCF service and I am trying to catch them using behavior extension.
When the message is received I am going through its headers collection.

Each header is of MessageHeaderInfo type which does not have a value property. 
How can I extract the value? It can be done with an ugly parsing (to remove the xml elements around the value) but it feels lame.

your help is most appriciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way you normally use message headers is by defining a DataContract (or an XmlSerializable class) to represent your header, then use [Message.Headers.GetHeader<T>()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms195389.aspx) to retrieve it. That method will do the deserialization and hand you a strongly typed object you can use.

Comment: it really works. I have another issue - it seems that If I am sending the headers in the request in a different order, some of them are not properly deserialized and I get null values. Is there any solution for that? I don't want that the order will be fixed.

Comment: I think you might want to make a separate question for that with more details. I've definitely haven't seen that before...